# If $\varphi$ is a linear functional, show that $\{\varphi\ge0\}^\circ=\{\varphi>0\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $\varphi\in E'\setminus\{0\}$ and $H:=\{\varphi\ge0\}$.

I would like to show that $H^\circ=\{\varphi>0\}$ and $\partial H=\{\varphi=0\}$.

Should be trivial enough. It's clear that $H$ is closed and hence $\partial H=H\setminus H^\circ$. So, we only need to determine $H^\circ$.

Now, $\{\varphi>0\}=\varphi^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is open and contained in $H$. So, we only need to show that if $x\in\{\varphi=0\}$, it cannot be an interior point of $H$. I think the correct approach is to take an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ and show that $B_\varepsilon(x)$ contains a point not in $H$. But how do we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi(x)$ is $0$ then $\phi[B(x, \delta)]$ is open and contains $0$ and so $B(x, \delta)$ contains points with $\phi(x) < 0$ for all $\delta>0$.

Comment: What are you denoting by $\phi[B(x, \delta)]$ Looks like the image of $B(x,\delta)$ under $\phi$, but why should that be open?

Comment: @0xbadf00d open mapping theorem. Work in the completion of $E$ if necessary..

Comment: Bigger hammer than needed. For $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$, every surjective $\mathbb{K}$-linear map of a topological $\mathbb{K}$-vector space to a finite-dimensional Hausdorff TVS is open.

Comment: I'm willing to assume that $E$ is complete, but don't we need $\varphi$ to be surjective in order to apply the open mapping theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer So, do we need to assume that $\varphi$ is surjective? Since I'm not aware of the result you mention (do you have a reference?), the open mapping theorem would be an easier tool for me.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, we need to assume surjectivity, for an open linear map is necessarily surjective. Here, $\varphi \in E'\setminus \{0\}$ gives the surjectivity. Reference: Exercise 1.10 in Rudin's _Functional Analysis_. (Note: continuity is not needed, and although Rudin requires a TVS to be Hausdorff, that isn't needed either, only the codomain needs to be Hausdorff.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, sure. Missed that for a moment. Regarding continuity: Without continuity, $H$ is not closed (unless $E$ is finite-dimensional) or am I missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d For your purpose, we need the continuity (otherwise $H$ wouldn't be closed; but we are given continuity of $\varphi$, so all is fine). For the theorem I mentioned continuity isn't required.